# Differentiated Login Response Based on Database Field: Express + Node + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, passport.js

I have a website with a tutorial page. Before a user can access deeper parts of the website, they must first have read the tutorial. In my mongo database I have set a field to check this as such:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

    finished_beta_tutorial: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    ....
```

When the user attempts to login, I want to send them to the Tutorial page if `finished_beta_tutorial` is false. And if they have seen it (where the field is `true`), I want to send them to some other page in the website.

I'm using Passport.js as my user management system, and I've gotten stuck with how to carry out this differentiated routing.

My login route looks like this:

```
// login
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('local', { 
        failureRedirect:'/users/login', 
        failureFlash: true
    });

    var condition = User.find({

    })
    if (req.user.finished_beta_tutorial === true) {
        req.flash('success', 'You are now logged in!');

        res.redirect('/dashboard/home');
    }
    else {
        req.flash('danger', 'Please read the Beta tutorial before continuing.');

        res.redirect('/users/slider');
    }
  }
);
```

The tricky part is that `req.user` returns `undefined` since the login process has not been completed yet, resulting in an error when I attempt to login. How can I fix this to allow for the split routing that I described above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your passport.authenticate route to:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
        failureRedirect:'/users/login', 
        failureFlash: true
    }), function(req, res) {

        if (req.user.finished_beta_tutorial) {
            req.flash('success', 'You are now logged in!');

            res.redirect('/dashboard/home');
        }
        else {
            req.flash('danger', 'Please read the Beta tutorial before continuing.');

           res.redirect('/users/slider');
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: I found another method, but it was messier than this. Yours is far better, thanks for the help.